# Можно ли запятыми по правилу факультативного обособления наречий обособлять «обычно»?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли запятыми по правилу факультативного обособления наречий обособлять *обычно*? Или его, если есть мегапауза, можно только тире или скобками?

> Арина-кошка, обычно, не любила говорить про Боярского, когда «Бизнесмен» звучал-таки вполкатушки.

Comment: Обычно лучше не списывать отовсюду, а самому решать задачи, сэр.  Я вам рассказала, как.

Comment: Перед *как* нет запятых.

Comment: Конечно, нет... Откуда там запятая?  Это факультативный знак-подчеркивание – у меня.  Чтобы вам лучше видеть.

Comment: Но вы её поставили, а нельзя так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**А почему нет?** *Обычно* — наречие, обозначающее повторяющееся действие, происходящее с какой-либо регулярностью. У Розенталя тоже есть пример с подобным — обособленным! — наречием:

> *Проходя Театральным переулком, я, **почти всегда**, видел у двери маленькой лавки человека* (М. Г.).

*Почти всегда* — наречие того же типа — следовательно, и *обычно* можно обособлять:

*Арина-кошка, обычно, не любила говорить про Боярского, когда «Бизнесмен» звучал-таки вполкатушки*.

Обособление, в общем-то, факультативное работает. Смотрите [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=115), можете найти тот пример.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*Арина-кошка, **обычно,** не любила говорить про Боярского, когда «Бизнесмен» звучал-таки вполкатушки.*

1. Сравнить: *Арина-кошка, **что характерно**, не любила говорить про Боярского, когда «Бизнесмен» звучал-таки вполкатушки.*

Обособление связано **с инверсией** обстоятельства.

2. Сравнить:  ***Обычно** (= что характерно) Арина-кошка, не любила говорить про Боярского, когда «Бизнесмен» звучал-таки вполкатушки.*

**Детерминант** относится ко всему сообщению.